# RPLCD libary not working

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio

I connected my 20x4 LCD module to Raspberry Pi like this: 
[image]

When I try to use [code](http://pastebin.com/M4D32fdi) from RaspberyPi-Spy it works but [RPLCD](https://github.com/dbrgn/RPLCD) doesn't.

This is how I initialize my LCD in 20x4.py (RPLCD test code)

```
lcd = CharLCD(pin_rs=7, pin_e=8, pins_data=[25, 24, 23, 18], numbering_mode=GPIO.BOARD, cols=20, rows=4, dotsize=8)
```

When I run the code(I renamed it to hr.py) I get this error:
[image]

I also noticed that in [RPLCD example](https://github.com/dbrgn/RPLCD#init-setup-teardown) he set's pin_rw to 18, while my pin_rw is grounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use RPi.GPIO you can specify one of two gpio numbering systems.

GPIO.BCM says you will use gpio numbers as defined by Broadcom.

GPIO.BOARD say you will use pin numbers.

The following diagram shows pin numbers and the gpios connected to them on a board with the 40 pin expansion header.

```
           pin  pin
3V3         1    2      5V
2 (SDA)     3    4      5V
3 (SCL)     5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
27         13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
           .......
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```

The Raspberry Pi-spy code uses BCM numbering. RPLCD uses pin numbering.

The channel sent is invalid message indicates that you are using a number outside the range expected. I.e. if using gpio numbering then a gpio not brought out to the expansion header.  If using a pin number, then a pin not connected to a gpio, e.g. a ground pin.

You need to ensure that you are using a consistent numbering scheme and that the wiring used is correct for that scheme.

Comment: I change the code to `lcd = CharLCD(pin_rs=26, pin_rw=6, pin_e=24, pins_data=[22, 18, 16, 12], numbering_mode=GPIO.BOARD, cols=20, rows=4, dotsize=8)` and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Pin 6 is a ground pin, and is not connected to a gpio.  If your intention is to ground the R/W line leave the wire where it is and just mention an unused gpio for pin_rw.  The software won't know the gpio is unconnected, but probably needs a gpio.